# Why is a client in javascript websocket not allowed to send custom ping/pong frames to server?

Tags: javascript, websocket, server, client

I have read that javascript websocket frames work in a way that the browser automatically responds to the ping from the server with a pong. Why is it not possible for the client to do the same and not rely on browser auto ping/pong?